# How to get the icons on GNOME shell back?

Tags: icons, indicator, gnome-shell

When I open Teamviewer, Steam or OBS in another, usually it will show small icons in the shell like this.

[image]

But in my laptop, there are no icons like these appeared in the shell when using Teamviewer, Steam or OBS.
Here are my indicator-applets installed in my laptop.
[image]

I am using Ubuntu 18.04. I have to run <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> and press 'r' to get these icons, but when restarting the system, they disappear again.

Could anyone please tell me how to solve this issue?
Thank you a lot in advance.